# Can I close a socket, just by its port number?

Tags: sockets, junit, port

I am testing a simple client/server application.  My unit tests on client side need the server up, but I seem to be getting hangs (individual tests work, but not more than one).

As part of my tearDown(), I thought it would be good to close the server socket, but... since I have no way of getting access to the server object, from the client code, I can't do a simple: serverSocket.close().  That said, I do know what port number the socket is running on, with the port number alone, is it possible to close a socket, irrespective of where/how the object using it resides?

Sorry for what is probably a trivial question... thanks...

I suppose another related question is... can I create a socket based on a port number already in use?

Comment: Don't understand your second question. You mean you want to pick a free port that doesn't clash with an existing one?

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to get the server software to close the port.

The only other alternative is killing the server: you can identify the process that has the port open with lsof or netstat, then kill the process. That's a brutal way to free a port though. In your case, you'd be much better off fixing your software not to hang!

Answer (score 0):

If the socket is in your process, what you can do is iterate over all file descriptors from 0 to `getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE)` and invoke `getsockname()` on each of them. If the call succeeds and the port number matches you have found your socket by port number (beware though, the may be multiple sockets with the same port number but bound to different addresses).

Comment: If the socket is in his process and he needs to do this, he's got some serious refactoring to do!

Comment: @NicholasWilson I would start with using a proper language though )))